# In a Vue child component, how do I access the attributes of the parent slot?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

When using slots, how do you access it's attribites?

In the example below I want to access the `label` and `v-model` attributes of the slot and display them inside divs.

**SomePage.vue** (the parent)

```
<template>
  <my-form>
    <template v-slot:inputSlot>
      <q-input label="First Name" v-model="inputValue" />
    </template>
  </my-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import MyForm from 'src/components/MyForm.vue';
const inputValue: Ref<string | undefined> = ref(undefined);
</script>
```

**MyForm.vue** (the child)

```
<template>
  <q-form>
    <slot name="inputSlot"></slot>
  </q-form>
  <div>
    <strong>{{ inputLabel }}</strong> <!--  This should display as "First Name" -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong>{{ inputValue }}</strong> <!--  This should display whatever was typed into inputValue on the parent -->
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
const inputLabel = ref();
const inputValue = ref();
</script>
```

P.S. In case you were wondering `q-form` and `q-input` are both [Quasar components](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#introduction).

Comment: You'll likely need to extract them from slot's vnode (in render function). This is a hack, there may be a better way depending on what you try to do. If a component is known to treat children in special way, they are usually provided to as a direct child and not as a slot, and then a parent decides how they should be transformed in render functon. You'll likely need to use custom MyInput instead of random children to know that it needs to be treated differently, i.e. asserting that MyForm's slot is MyInput